# Error while trying to build the NX dev container

Tags: docker, nrwl, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I'm trying to contribute with [NX project](https://github.com/nrwl/nx), but I;m getting an error on  the dev container while trying to install the dependencies.

VSCode dev container extension build the container, and runned the `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade` commands sucessifully, but when it's try to run the pnpm install, it's throwing an error

```
 ERR_PNPM_ENOENT  ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile '/workspaces/nx/.pnpm-store/v3/files/4e/e1c88f8c3f4e4cd34cb6c00339bf9d6d036ff4ade3af49e871cc8966b84c729d8b75492acc6413c9a664ac00a57958223ac13c4229da8c62ebe6a53e4f783f' -> '/workspaces/nx/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.9.1_@swc+core@1.3.86_@types+node@18.19.8_typescript@5.3.3/node_modules/ts-node_tmp_767/dist/cjs-resolve-hooks.d.ts'
```

I've tried to rebuild the container some times, and run `pnpm install` directly, but the first throws the same error, while the second throws `Error: Cannot find module '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage/d79600a30618d2a2c36ab67ceb766aae/ms-vscode.js-debug/bootloader.js'`

It's my first time using dev containers, so I have no clue how to handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

A content-addressable store is utilized by pnpm for managing dependencies. Dev Containers often mount project directories from the host machine's filesystem (e.g., `/workspaces/nx`), relying on the host's directory structure being available.

Thus these dependencies may end up in the mounted directory, which can be confirmed with `pnpm store path` command. To avoid compatibility issues or file access permissions errors, pnpm can be configured to use a local directory within the container itself for its store:

```bash
pnpm config set store-dir ~/.local/share/pnpm/store
```

*Note*: `node_modules` will need to be deleted and the dependencies reinstalled (`pnpm install`).

Additional information:

- This issue is discussed in https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/5803.
- Additionally pnpm's [FAQ](https://pnpm.io/faq#does-pnpm-work-across-multiple-drives-or-filesystems) recommends package stores to be in the same file system.

> Does pnpm work across multiple drives or filesystems?
>
> The package store should be on the same drive and filesystem as installations, otherwise packages will be copied, not linked. This is due to a limitation in how hard linking works, in that a file on one filesystem cannot address a location in another.